# Seeking Geospatial Tools for SketchUp?

Tags: software-recommendations, orthophoto, sketchup

I was wondering if anyone knows of geospatial tools that work in SketchUp?

I know if GeoSketch, which allows a user to import ortho imagery, DEMs, shapefiles and GPS enabled photographs into SketchUp for 3D model creation.  I am looking for other geospatial tools that are designed for SketchUp, but I am having issues finding any.

I am interested in geospatial tools that work within SketchUp.

Comment: FME can read and write Google SketchUp http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#sketchup/sketchup.htm

Comment: Yes I know that, I was thinking more for tools that work inside of SketchUp.

Comment: "Geospatial tools that work within SketchUp" is a little vague. Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: No, as I have said in the original question, I have found a tool that does this, but I am looking for any alternatives.  The tool I found does ortho imagery, DEMs, shapefiles and GPS photos, so something along the same lines.  Plugins, extensions, etc.  I am trying to identify any other tools that are available; rather than needing to spend $3,600 per seat of GeoSketch.

Comment: My feeling is that there are not a lot of geospatial tools available for SketchUp.  But I wanted to ask the community if they know any.  This will be helpful for moving forward for me over the next few months.

Comment: You are probably right, if they are able to charge that much for it then there is probably little competition. However if you could define what you are actually trying to accomplish (specify your *needs*, rather than wants) then perhaps people can make better suggestions.

Comment: I would like to be able to import ortho Avery and vector data to be able to build 3D models from Geospatial data.

Comment: Wouldn't "tools that work inside of SketchUp" be plugins, by definition?  If so, did you review the [list of SketchUp Plugins](http://www.sketchup.com/download/plugins.html)?

Comment: Yes I have reviewed that list, as well as many others.  I have yet to find many plugins for geospatial data.

Comment: This would result in a list of X apps. Wouldn't this be better as a community wiki? It has no definitive answer.

Comment: Maybe, but a definite answer could be none.  Or it could be GeoSketch, the plugin I found; which would answer my question.

Comment: actually there is 1 plugin that i know to [export .shp file](http://enja.org/enjshape/) to sketchup. So far i try, it only work for google sketchup 7.